# Use Arduino to generate sin wave modulated by gold code

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno

I am trying to use Arduino to generate sin wave and gold code is used to determine when the wave will have a phase shift. However, the output is not performed as I expected. Sometimes, it does not occur any phase shift for consequent ten cycles, which should not happen according to our definition of gold code array. Which part of the code could I try to fix the problem?

```
int gold_code[]={1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1, 1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1, -1, 1, 1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1};


void loop() 
{
  int n = sizeof(gold_code)/sizeof(gold_code[0]);
  byte bsin[128];
  int it;
  unsigned long tm0;
  unsigned int tm;
  for(int i=0;i<128;i++)
  {
    bsin[i] = 8 + (int)(0.5 + 7.*sin( (double)i*3.14159265/64.));
  }
  int count=0;
  int count1=0;

  Serial.println(n);

  tm0 = micros();
  while(true)
  {

    tm = micros() - tm0;
    if(tm > 511)
    {
      tm0 = tm0+512;
      tm -= 512;
      count++;
      //Serial.println(gold_code[count%n]);
    }
    tm = (tm >> 2) ;
    if(gold_code[count%n]==0){
      PORTB = bsin[tm];
    }
    else{
      PORTB = 16-bsin[tm];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're not adding anything to the argument to `sin`, so how can there be a phase shift? General form is y=Asin(Bx + C).

Comment: How fast is your processor? One thought, you should make the `if(tm > 511)` to a `while(tm > 511)` just in case there are any time issues and the loop takes longer then 512 uS and you somehow end up with `tm` > 1023. You could look into your processor speed and how long it takes to update a port. Also make sure you keep the print line in the loop commented out or you will likely get timing issue because of the delay to print.

Comment: Since A-Asin(Bx)=A+Asin(Bx+pi), this method can shift the phase by pi.

Comment: I also worried about the speed of my processor. I will check this later. Regarding the print line. It was only used when I was testing. The problem still occurred when I commented that line.

Comment: The modulo operation is a division.  That's the slowest operation on any of the Arduino CPUs.  Find a faster way of limiting the value of `count`.  A division (or modulo) is at least 19 cycles, that's close to 40% of the loop time wasted right there.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `count`  eventually overflows and becomes negative.  This, in conjunction with the modulo operation is a sign (pun intended) of a disaster waiting to happen.

Use a different method for limiting the value of `count` to the bounds of your `gold_code`array.

You should expect a significant increase in frequency after removing the modulo operation, so you may need to add some pacing to your loop.

The pacing in your loop is wrong. Variable `count` increments 4 times as fast as your phase counter.

Also, @Edward Karak raises a valid point.  To do a proper phase shift, you should add (or subtract) from `tm`, not from the sin value.

[EDIT]  I was not quite happy with the way the phase shift is handled. It just doesn't feel right to advance the gold counter at the same pace as the phase counter.  So I added a separate timer for that.  Advances in the gold_code array every 8 microseconds for now, but you can change it to whatever you're supposed to have.

as in:

```
unsigned char tm0 = 0;
unsigned char tm0_gold = 0;

const unsigned char N = sizeof(gold_code) / sizeof(gold_code[0]);
unsigned char     phase = 0; 

for(;;)
{
    // pacing for a stable frequency
    unsigned char mic = micros() & 0xFF;
    if (mic - tm0_gold >= 8)
    {
        tm0_gold = mic;

        // compute and do the phase shift
        if (++count >= N) 
            count -= N;

        if (gold_code[count] > 0)  // you have == 0 in your code, but that doesn't make sense.
            phase += 16;           // I can't make any sense of what you are trying to do, 
                                   // so I'll just add 45° of phase for each positive value
                                   // you'll probably want to make your own test here
    }

    if (mic - tm0 >= 4)
    {
        tm0 = mic;

        // advance the phase. keep within the LUT bounds
        if (++phase >= 128)
            phase -= 128;

        // output
        PORTB = bsin[phase];
    }
}
```

For frequency stability, you will want to move the sine generator to a timer interrupt, after debugging.  This will free up your loop() to do some extra control.

I don't quite understand why `count` increments as fast as the phase counter.
You may want to increment `count` at a slower pace to reach your goal.

Comment: I've made a lot of edits, since I found other issues while reading your code in more details.  I think you'll want a separate timer for the phase changes.